# Recursion example in Java: is return necessary?

Tags: java, recursion, return

Do I need `return x;` statement here? The printout is the same whether I use the `return x;`
or I make the method `void` and don't use a return statement at all.

```
package RecursionTry1;

public class RecursionTry {
    public int run(int x)
    {
        if(x<5)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
            run(x+1);

        }
        System.out.println(x);
        return x;  //<---- Do I need this return statement?
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RecursionTry A = new RecursionTry();
        A.run(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is of return type `int`. Printing doesn't return an `int`. You can make your method `void` to avoid returning an `int` if you just want to print in your method.

Comment: Yes, but my question is why this gives you the same print out as you use: Void and no return combination.

Comment: You make no use of the return value anywhere. You could just as well `return 42;` or `return -1;`. It makes no difference.

Comment: By the way, the output is 5,4,3,2,1, but since the INNER MOST recursion executed, the X has been changed to 5, why still 4, 3, 2, 1 being printed?

Comment: "I  don't use a return" (value) and the method never uses the return value, so it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to return any value. because you don't use your returned value when it returned.

For example If you have this code then you need to return something:

```
retvalue = run(x)
```

or

```
System.out.println(run(x));
```

But you don't use returned value of run() function
And when you don't want to return anything it's better to use **void** function

you can read more about java functions from [Learn java online site, functions page.](http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions)

Comment: Because you are running System.out.println(x); and after that running the function again with x + 1 run(x+1);

Comment: So in your first run the x is 1 and in second run the x is 2 but if you used System.out.println(run(x+1)); then you should return the value of x, If it was your answer then please accept the answer so it helps other people in community too